# What is the status of professional video game players?

Tags: halacha, technology, employment, edim-witnesses, games-toys

A friend remarked to me that playing video games professionally today is the equivalent of professional gamblers in the times of the talmud, specifically in that both are not involved in "Yishuvo shel Olam" (loosely: the substantive betterment of the world).

Do any modern day halachic authorities discuss the occupation of playing video games professionally?

Comment: Why would they be equated to gamblers and not professional athletes?

Comment: @rosends they are not performing any athletic feats, I would assume

Comment: @rosends why should those be different

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think that they should be. The question seems to treat video gamers as distinct.

Comment: @rikitikitembo that begs a host of question, not the least of which is, if that is quantifiably true, why does it matter?

Comment: @rosends on the one hand https://www.forbes.com/sites/insertcoin/2013/07/14/the-u-s-now-recognizes-esports-players-as-professional-athletes/ but on the other I'm not sure why it matters either from a halachic standpoint either.

Comment: FWIW I just asked Rav Aviner this question and he said it would be forbidden for the reason I proposed as well as moshav leitzim

Comment: The question is about psul leedut?

Comment: @kouty not necessarily

Comment: So what may be the problem, there is no Asmachta  and not Baki byishuvo Shel olam is not prohibited per se.

Comment: It is a common mistake to think that, rooted in differences in our economies. Today everyone who represents a niche in the national economy is taking a part in Yeshuvo Shel Olam, even by providing additional income and paying taxes. Don't forget, that just like other athletes, their work provides opportunities for hundreds of other jobs

Comment: @AlBerko so did/does gambling

Comment: @rikitikitembo I understand your confusion. In the times of the sages, gambling wasn't a part of the national economy. Those people did not generate any extra jobs, all they did was to exchange money between themselves. Today gambling is a huge entertainment industry, generating thousands of jobs, lots of taxing etc. So it surely falls under Yeshuvo shel Olam.

Comment: @rikitikitembo So is prostitution, if you wish (from Yeshuvo shel olam point only, of course).

Comment: @rikitikitembo Does R. Aviner hold the same regarding professional athletes (actors, many degrees in the Arts etc.) ? If he hasn’t voiced his opinion, you’d do a great service for the community if you were able to extend yourself and find out if so and/or his reasoning.

Comment: "professional **gamblers** in the times of the talmud, specifically in that both are not involved in "Yishuvo shel Olam" (loosely: the substantive **betterment of the world**)." Source?

Answer (score -1):

The same would probably therefore extend to singers or anything like that.
Besides for the fact that I believe there are other reasons that gambling is assur, gamers technically are supplying entertainment (such as singers), whereas gamblers are just... gambling.

Comment: Please see my other comment to you with rules of the site. Remember to include sources in your answers, this is not a discussion site, and your personal opinions are of less value than on these sites. Looking forward to your ongoing participation as you seem to have a lot to offer.